# Stanford Parser as a Google App Engine Service

Tags: google-app-engine, stanford-nlp

I'm new to Goole App Engine. I'm struggling to find a way to use Stanford Parser as a backend for a mobile app (iOS, Android). Is it possible to run the Parser as a service in GAE so that the app can send the string in wich the parsing will be done and after the processing, the app gets a JSON with the results?

If yes, any hints or tutorial that you can direct me to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your exact question, but I'm also very interested in this.

Have you tried running the parser locally on iOS or Android? I suspect it would be somewhat slow, but I wonder if it's "tolerably slow" for small sentences. The official page just mentions a 100MB memory minimum, I can't find any mention of a minimum requirement for CPU power.

Here they explain how they run their own online parser:
https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/parser-user/2011-March/000954.html

Comment: Hi,I think Stanford Parser is not available for iOS objective-C. Maybe it could work with Android. I'm going to try to set it up in Google App Engine as a servlet. Thank you for the explanation link.