# How can I generate parse trees of English sentences on iOS?

Tags: ios, nlp, linguistics

I would like to generate constituency-based parsed trees of English sentences within an iOS application.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree

My current options appear to be:

- Write my own tree generation on top of POS tagging from NSLinguisticTagger.
- Embed the python-based NLTK into my app.
- Create or use a server based approach.

Could anyone recommend one of these approaches, or perhaps suggest another?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159751/stanford-parser-as-a-google-app-engine-service) about using the Standford parser on iOS.

Comment: have you find your own way? I'm struggling for now.

Comment: I didn't get much further with this I'm afraid. I was simply looking for easy ways to get comprehensive linguistic information about texts. I will probably end up going the custom route.

Answer (score 0):

maybe that will help:

JavaScript is pretty popular language and it is possible to run JS in objective C code
check **Integrating JavaScript into Native Apps** wwdc 2013 session

so maybe you can find solution in JS and than use it in native objc code.